# Dragon berthing - Is the orientation specific to the orbital conditions, or always the same?

Tags: spacex, dragon, berthing, cbm

When the CanadArm catches the Dragon grapple fixture and attaches/berths it to the CBM on the ISS, is the orientation of the Dragon in the berthing port fixed and the same every berthing?

Or do they position it specific to the ISS orbital paths.

Comment: I would imagine it is the same or similar because there is only 1 grapple point on dragon and the CanadArm manoeuvres are practised by the crew regularly. Small variations are likely though but probably only a few degrees.

Comment: @tl8 The CanadArm has some freedom on movement and I wonder if it can berth it with different rotations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far it has always been the same

CRS-1

[image]

CRS-2

[image]

CRS-3

[image]

CRS-4

[image]

CRS-5

[image]